# Which segue should I use to show a view controller vertically?

Tags: swift

First and foremost i'm still new to Swift so please bear with me. Say i'm at view controller A (which is the root view controller in the navigation hierarchy) and I want view controller B to appear as  a popup (cover the entire screen). **I want that popup and to remain part of the navigation hierarchy.** Then from that popup push to view controller C with a horizontal transition. How would I do this? I am using segues. I just don't know which segue to use. Should I use a modal or popover segue to go from view controller A to view controller B? Or should I simply use a push segue and use a custom transition? I'd prefer not to use a custom transition but let me know what you think.

Comment: Do you want to present it from bottom or as a pop up is mandatory?

Comment: I want to present it from the bottom, and I also want to be able to transition to another view controller with a horizontal (right to left) transition afterwards.

Comment: Try the below code and lemme know if any problem comes. Will modify as per requirement.

Comment: I'll try it right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embed your ViewController B into a navigation controller and present the navigation controller modally.

Comment: I did this but when going from view controller B to view controller C, the transition is vertical, instead of horizontal (right to left). It's almost as if view controller C is not part of the navigation hierarchy.

Comment: How are you pushing the viewController C onto the navigation stack? Show your code

Comment: I'm using a push segue: self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "pushToChosenContentVC", sender: nil)

Comment: In the storyboard, what is the type of `pushToChosenContentVC` segue?

Comment: A Show ( e.g Push ) segue

Comment: Actually I just figured out that presenting a view controller modally removes it from the navigation stack. I've added a navigation controller to view controller B in the storyboard and it fixed my problem. I got it working the way I wanted. Thank you for the help!

Comment: That is exactly what I said in my answer isn't it? That is to embed your viewController B into a navigation controller

Comment: I must have misinterpreted your answer. You definitely did say that. I'll mark your answer as correct. Once again, thank you for the help.

Comment: Glad to be of help

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to present the VC from bottom.

```
let alertVC = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CustomAlertViewController") as! CustomAlertViewController

alertVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.overCurrentContext

self.present(alertVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Then further use push for other VC's

Comment: It presents itself modally which is fine, but when I go to push to another view controller afterwards, instead often transitioning from right to left, it appears as another popup.